# ScrollView with ImageView setting the same inset for zoom

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I would like to create a custom image cropper. I have an `UIScrollView` with an `UIImageView` in it. 
There is a fix area on the screen which will be the cropped part of the image. I would like to set the inset of the ScrollView to let the image to be scrolled to the edges of that area on the screen (like on the picture).

The `UIImageView` is set to `.scaleAspectFill`.

I would like to ask some help how to get the correct insets.

[image]

Comment: Try something like: `scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: x, y: y), animated: true)`. Also I think you need to add an overlay view as a _sibling_ view of the scroll view but with `centerY`, `trailing` and `leading` constraints.

Comment: I want to achieve that the edge of image can be scrollable to the edge of the fixed area (the green on picture), so I need to set the inset (`scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`) in my opinion, but the real question is how to find out the correct values.

Comment: I see, for the initial offset I think you could query the `view.frame.y` or `view.frame.x`. Note that this would have to be done after the view hierarchy has been loaded.